# How do I use Mac Keyboard Icons in WordPress

Tags: visual-editor

This is a dumb question all right, but everytime I search for the answer I'm just getting results for keyboard shortcuts to control wordpress. In my blog I need to include the images for key combinations for a mac keyboard. How can I do this? If there's a plugin, it'd be really nice to show the keystroke combinations as little key icons - if it supports windows icons to then even better!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any comments on why this has been downvoted? If there's a problem with the question let me know so I can fix it

Comment: Hi! You likely got downvoted because (while interesting) your question borders being not in scope here on two points - being specific to WordPress (working with these characters is same as elsewhere) and implying plugin is desirable answer (asking for plugin recommendationds is not in scope here).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I see why it was downvoted now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is rather simple – you type them. :) When properly configured WP should be able to support Unicode characters for <kbd>[⌘](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2318/index.htm)</kbd> and <kbd>[⌥](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2325/index.htm)</kbd>. Even when not you can fall back to [numeric character references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference) (`&#8984;` and `&#8997;` respectively).

Windows key has no Unicode symbol and is typically abbreviated as <kbd>Win</kbd>.

[`<kbd>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/kbd) HTML element is appropriate to use for keyboard commands and is often already styled in theme (if it is thorough enough).